# HTML viewport meta tag - Incorrect PPI/DPI/DPR values on android browsers

Tags: javascript, css, browser, responsive-design, cross-browser

I ran the code below on [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/responsive) to identify various resolutions and DPI values the browser reports on various android devices.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1' >
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
            var w = window;
            var d = document;
            var e = d.documentElement;
            var g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || (window.screen.deviceXDPI / window.screen.logicalXDPI);

            document.write("dpi="+dpr);
            document.write("<br>"+w.innerWidth+" x "+w.innerHeight);
            document.write("<br>"+navigator.userAgent);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have summarized the results below:
First column gives the device name, second column gives the device resolution (as per browserstack), third column is the OS, fourth column gives the DPI/PPI/DPR value, final column gives the resolution returned by Javascript.

```
Galaxy Tab 4,           800 x 1280     Android 4.4             1      980 x 1230
Kindle Fire HDX 7,      600 x 960      Android 4.3             1      800 x 1230
google nexus 4,         384 x 640      android 4.2             1      384 x 590 
galaxy note 3,          360 x 640      android 4.3             1      432 x 718 
galaxy s5,              360 x 640      android 4.4             1      980 x 590 
galaxy s5 mini,         360 x 640      android 4.4             1      980 x 590 
iphone 6 plus,          414 x 736      ios 8.3                 3      414 x 692 
iphone 6,               375 x 667      ios 8.3                 2      375 x 623 
ipad Air                768 x 1024     ios 8.3 (safari)        2      768 x 1064 
ipad mini 2,            768 x 1024     ios 8.3 (safari)        2      768 x 1064 
iphone 5s,              320 x 588      ios 7.0                 2      320 x 504
```

I am instead getting (x,y) resolution values

1. that are greater than what is reported for that device. (compare column 2 with 5)
2. And the DPI value is always 1 (column 4). For example, Kindle fire is reporting a DPI of 1 which is clearly incorrect.
3. The x,y values are the same for both landscape and portrait modes. ( not given in result above, but onserved on browserstack. This was happening only for Android devices. The iOS devices were flipping the (x,y) values correctly when switching between landscape and portrait mode.)

Could somebody help me understand why this is happening?